# Can't convert value from datatable to datetime

Tags: powershell

Using powershell 5.1

I have a function called that returns a string representing a date like this
"4/22/2019 12:00:00 AM"

```
function Get-LastLogTime() {
    $lastRunDate =  Get-SQLData  "." "AdHoc" "SELECT TOP 1 o.LogTime FROM dbo.FAQlog o  WHERE o.RecordsSent = 1 ORDER BY o.LogTime DESC" 

    return $lastRunDate
}
```

Where LogTime is the usual Datetime SQL type and `Get-SQLData` is another function that returns a datatable. 
If I just check the return value, I get something like this

```
LogTime
-------
4/22/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

Ok, great, but I need to compare this date to the current date. So, I do something like this but i get an error on the line trying to convert `$testDate` to datetime.

```
# test
$testDate = Get-LastLogTime
([DateTime]$testDate) -lt (Get-Date)
```

If I just do a simple comparison at the command line, it works, eg.

```
([DateTime]"4/22/2019 12:00:00 AM" ) -lt (Get-Date)
```

Comment: when you do `$TestDate.GetType()`, what do you see? i suspect it is an object with a property named `.LogTime`. if that is so, then you need to use `$TestDate.LogTime` in your test.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that was it.  Sure enough.  Thanks!

Comment: kool! you are very welcome ... glad to have helped a little bit! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

It works with 
    ([DateTime]"4/22/2019 12:00:00 AM" )
Because you are casting DateTime on a String.

Return value of `Get-LastLogTime` is not a string probably and casting it to a Datetime does not work. 
`get-LastLogTime | get-member` will show you the methods you have available on the returned data type such as, for instance, `ToString`, and that can be used to perform the comparison.